# Curses menu module with own methods

Tags: python, python-curses

I'm currently trying to get a small console menu running for my program.
I found the curses-menu module on [PyPi curses-menu](https://pypi.org/project/curses-menu/) and tried my luck with it.

The curses menu has a `FunctionItem` which calls python functions but sadly I can't see the output on the console. Here's my example code:

```
# Import the necessary packages
from cursesmenu import *
from cursesmenu.items import *

def hello(x):
    print("Hello {}".format(x))

# Create the menu
menu = CursesMenu("Title", "Subtitle")

# Create some items

# A FunctionItem runs a Python function when selected
function_item = FunctionItem("Call a Python function", hello, [3])

# Once we're done creating them, we just add the items to the menu
menu.append_item(function_item)

# Finally, we call show to show the menu and allow the user to interact
menu.show()
```

`hello` is called with the `3` as the parameter and it also creates the output but I can't see it on the console because the menu is still there.

Sadly I don't know what to do now with it. I'd be happy if someone could help me with this issue or tell me a better module for a console menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an easier to use text user interface library for python, have a look at [pythondialog](http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/) instead.

If you really want to use the curses menu extension instead, you need to invest learning time to learn curses, because it is not easy to use. Have a look at the [ncurses programming howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). It teaches ncurses programming in C. After learning curses basics and how to use the curses menu extension in C from this howto, you can transfer what you have learned to python.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into pythondialog. Curses was just the first module which convinced me to try it.